# SQL Assign Custom values to those rows with similar IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
|id|last|
|2 |NULL|
|2 |2018|
|3 |NULL|
|3 |NULL|
|4 |2011|
|4 |2013|
```

This is what my current table looks like. A new 'status' column is to be created for each 'id' that must have the below 3 values.

```
1 - If Similar id and only one NULL value
2 - If Similar id and no NULL value
0 - If Similar id and both NULL value
```

EXAMPLE: Id 2 will get 1, id 3 will be assigned 0 and id 4 will get 2. There can be only 2 similar ids in the id table (there are no 3 values of 2 or 4)

```
I could find the similar id, but having difficulties writing the cases
select id
from table
group by id
having count(id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can determine the status values by using aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN last IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 1
             THEN 1
             WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN last IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
             THEN 2
             WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN last IS NULL THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
             THEN 0 ELSE -1 END AS status
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT t1.*, t2.status
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Note that I assign a status value of -1 to any `id` which does not meet one of the three criteria.  This would include any `id` which only appears once, among other edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
select a.id, last,
case 
     when exists(select 1 from _table b where a.id = b.id and coalesce(b.last,0) <> coalesce(a.last,0) and (a.last is null or b.last is null)) 
       then 1  
     when exists(select 1 from _table b where a.id = b.id 
       and coalesce(b.last,0) <> coalesce(a.last,0))
       and not exists(select 1 from _table b where a.id = b.id 
       and b.last is null)
       then 2  
     when exists(select 1 from _table b where a.id = b.id  )
       and exists(select 1 from _table b where a.id = b.id and b.last is null and a.last is null having count(*) =
       (select count(*) from _table b where a.id = b.id))
       then 0  
 end as status
from _table a
```

Output:

```
id  last    status
2   NULL    1
2   2018    1
3   NULL    0
3   NULL    0
4   2011    2
4   2013    2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per `id`:

```
select id,
       (case count(*) filter (value is null)
             when 1 then 1
             when 0 then 2
             when 2 then 3
        end) as status
from t
group by id;
```

If you want this as a column on the original data, use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case count(*) filter (value is null) over (partition by id)
             when 1 then 1
             when 0 then 2
             when 2 then 3
        end) as status
from t;
```